# hashHistory, _escaped_fragment_, and Google

Tags: seo, react-router, google-search

I've been working with React Router for some time now and I've been using `hashHistory` to handle routing. At some point I am going to transition the app to `browserHistory`, but I'm curious as to why Google's "Fetch as Google" feature does not appear to work for anything other than the root route (`/`). It's clear that it's rendering something, just not the routes not handled by the server. (Image below)

[image]

I see that Google has [deprecated their AJAX crawling scheme](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html), which leads me to believe that I no longer need to deal with `?_escaped_fragment_=`, but even so, I cannot get Google to render any other routes.

For example, the site is `www.learnphoenix.io` and the lessons are listed under `www.learnphoenix.io/#/phoenix-chat/lessons`. Yet, Google's [Fetch as Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468?hl=en) feature in webmaster redirects to the homepage and only renders the homepage. Using `_escaped_fragment_` leads to the same result.

Is there a way to allow Google to index my site using `hashHistory`, or do I just have to accept that only my homepage will be indexed until I switch to `browserHistory`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, it seems that google ignores url fragments (#). According to this article, which may be dated, using #! will tell google that the fragments can be used to define different canonical pages.

https://www.oho.com/blog/explained-60-seconds-hash-symbols-urls-and-seo

It's worth a shot, though Hashbang isn't supported by ReactRouter, again, because its supposed to be deprecated.

A better option might be to just bite the bullet and use `browserHistory` (pushState) in your react-router. The problem with that is if you're running a static server-less app, paths like `/phoenix-chat/lessons` will return a 404. In AWS, there is a hack around that too. Setting your 404 page to be your app index page.

http://blog.boushley.net/2015/10/29/html5-deep-link-on-amazon-s3/

Feels dirty, but again, worth a shot. Hopefully there's something of value in this answer for you!

Comment: Yeah, that's probably as good as we're going to get. I guess with single page apps you really need to make sure it's literally a single page as far as Google is concerned.